# Azure Automation: Calling a URL

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I am new to Azure Automation. I want to call a URL and get its HTML once every weekday morning. This is what I have written so far.

```
workflow Wakeup-Url
{
    Param 
    (  
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] 
        $Url
    )

    $day = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek
    if ($day -eq 'Saturday' -or $day -eq 'Sunday'){
        exit
    }

    $output = ""
    InlineScript {"$Using:output = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(`"$Using:Url`");"}
    write-output $output
}
```

Its not giving me the HTML in the output when I test the runbook. Instead what I get in the output pane is:

> = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://my.url.com/abc.html");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your InlineScript is currently just outputting a string containing your script, since you put quotes around the entire expression:

```
InlineScript {"$Using:output = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(`"$Using:Url`");"}
```

This is what you want I think:

```
$output = InlineScript { (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$Using:Url"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Azure Runbook scheduler. I used code below to trigger an URL call.

```
Function OutputStatus($type,$status) { 
    Write-Output "$type | $status"; 
}

Function Get-HTTPSStatus($url,$type) { 
    $HTTPSStatus = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Get –UseBasicParsing 
    if ($HTTPSStatus.StatusCode -eq "200") { 
     return OutputStatus -type $type -status "Success" 
    } else { 
     return OutputStatus -type $type -status "Error" 
    } 
}
Get-HTTPSStatus "http://www.google.com" "Google Website"
```

Source: https://sharepointyankee.com/2018/01/29/creating-runbooks-in-azure-and-calling-them-from-sharepoint-using-webhooks-and-flow/

Answer (score -1):

This should be a more simple approach than using the Webclient

`$output =  (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.google.com -UseBasicParsing).Content`